# Microsoft application - Redirect URI allows 'localhost' but not '127.0.0.1'

Tags: asp.net, azure, redirect, oauth, adal

I have developed an application that allows MSA (Microsoft Account) authentication. I have registered my app here: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.

When testing my app locally, I can access my app with no problem at my SSL URL of https://localhost:44300, and MSA works fine. When I registered my app, I used https://localhost:44300/signin-microsoft as the Redirect URI.

**Problem:** I can also access my app at https://127.0.0.1:44300, as one would expect. However, MSA here doesn't work. The error page says, `We're unable to complete your request.
Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.` And the URL of the error page reveals that the error is with a mismatch in the Redirect URI: `https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application.`

In the Microsoft Apps page, when I try to update the Redirect URI from https://localhost:44300/signin-microsoft to https://127.0.0.1:44300/signin-microsoft, it doesn't allow me to save my change and it shows me this error: `Your URL can't contain a query string or invalid special characters`, and it provides a 'Learn More' link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-redirect-uris

After reading the info in this link, I see nowhere that a URI like mine (https://127.0.0.1:44300/signin-microsoft) would be an unacceptable URL, as I'm not breaking any of their rules: I have no invalid characters, no query strings, etc.

**My research:** Looking online, people are getting the `Your URL can't contain a query string or invalid special characters` because they are actually using a query string or invalid special characters, such as in this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f638860-ea57-4f0e-85e0-b28e1e357fe2/office-365-app-authorization-redirect-uri-issue?forum=WindowsAzureAD. I couldn't find a case where someone has entered a valid URI and they weren't allowed to save it.

**Why I need 127.0.0.1 to work:** I need to expose this website, which is running on my local box. In order to have the website running without having an instance of Visual Studio opened all the time, I'm using csrun to host my website in Azure local fabric (by the way, my app is an Azure Cloud Service, with a ASP.NET MVC 5 app as a web role). I followed this instruction for csrun: http://www.bardev.com/2013/03/12/how-to-deploy-application-to-windows-azure-compute-emulator-with-csrun/. Using csrun, it allowed me to host my website in https://127.0.0.1:444 (but, as with https://127.0.0.1:44300, MSA doesn't work). My end goal is to expose this website with a public URL using ngrok (https://www.sitepoint.com/use-ngrok-test-local-site/), so that anyone can access my site.

Therefore, my main question is: how can I have the Redirect URI be  https://127.0.0.1:44300/signin-microsoft instead of https://localhost:44300/signin-microsoft?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, will look into this and get back to you.

Comment: @DanielDobalian thanks, it does sound like it's a bug. Can you please post as an answer if you are able to confirm this? Btw, what team in Microsoft are you part of?

Comment: @DanielDobalian were you able to find an answer to this?

Comment: We're still looking into the problem.  I'll post back when I have more info.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you access this portal through https://identity.microsoft.com as this is the only way the steps below will work.

You can get around this error right now by adding the reply URL through the manifest. Login to [the portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), select the app you want to configure, and scroll down and hit the `Edit Application Manifest` button.  Then you can add your `https://127.0.0.1:44300/` to the `replyUrls` field.

There's some funny behavior that will only allow this right now if you only register other localhost reply Urls.  If this is the only reply URL you need then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: it's May 2022 and i stumbled upon this error today, changing redirect url in manifest worked for me, frontend UI in azure does not allow http//127.0.0.1